# How can to convert german.data file to .arff file?

Tags: arff

Hy

I want to convert this file **http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/german/** to .arff file because I want to use in weka, but i get an error while convert the file.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your data file to .csv using microsoft excel.

Then convert yout .csv file to .arff using "save" facility of weka explorer.